# Answering own question

Tags: discussion

When I joined I found *this possibility* interesting but asked myself if it is ever used.

But three days ago I asked: [How is weight distributed when legs are astride?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134242/how-is-weight-distributed-when-legs-are-astride) ? and got 0 answer.

As I needed the information I did some research and found a possible answer:

-I suppose that after 3 days I can answer my question,

- I suppose that if I post it I cannot upvote it, but,
- if it remains the **only** answer, what happens? I suppose I cannot accept my own answer

*Technical Note*: probably it's my poor eyesight, but at Physics. SE when a word is linked to an URL, it is terribly difficult for me to notice it. I keep swinging the mouse on every word to check if the colour changes.
Is it possible to make it more visible, as it happens in other sites of SE, making it of  a different colour **before** the mouse touches it? Even here at Meta it looks better

EDIT:

> *The only reservation I have is that your question is rather elementary*

I discovered it is, the point is that there are always doubts, when physics is concerned, anyway  we both answered such an *elementary* question [Why is acceleration constant in this example?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132860/why-is-acceleration-constant-in-this-example) or such a *silly* one: [Describing Objects in the First Dimension](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132680/describing-objects-in-the-first-dimension)

Probably for you it is an exception, but, as I am more ignorant than a student, answering simple question is for me ordinary run of the mill: race between hare and tortoise,  etc,,[Two runners on two different tracks](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133833/two-runners-on-two-different-tracks/133860#133860), etc. This last is really elementary, but it sparked of an interesting controversy nobody will ever settle. And what about this:[Determining the decay constant for a damped wave](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134468/determining-the-decay-constant-for-a-damped-wave), is it less elementary than mine?

Should I delete my question?, but *I thought this practice is discouraged*.

Personally I am content with my solution I do not need to post it for other members. If future viewers will have same proble, will post same question again. (btw: the horizontal friction it is not easy, unless you are an engineer). It seems that our average viewer is worried by spaghetti and meatballs and how you can run away fron your shadow!!!

Comment: The linked words are a different colour before you mouse-over them. But I agree, sometimes it's hard to tell when words are linked. A couple times I'd never have known that words were linked if I hadn't been the one who linked them.

Comment: I say post your own answer. Shoot, even if it's just so you never lose it and can go back and look it up. No need to wonder "Shoot, which hard drive did I back that up on!!!" years down the road when you need to do something similar. Answer it, put it in the cloud!

Comment: @tpg2114, thanks for the encouragement, I hesitated as I have been already showered by downvotes, and also as it _looks odd_ to me, answer your own question, accept your own question..., everybody, I suppose would choose his own, right?

Comment: @bobie Not always. I've seen on other places where somebody posts their own answer and somebody comes along and gives an even better one. When you post your own answer, it bumps the post back to the front page giving people who may not have seen it a chance to see it again. It's possible people just missed it before and that's why it went unanswered.

Comment: @tpg2114, I posted it [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134242/how-is-weight-distributed-when-legs-are-astride/134686#134686), let me know if it's good!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't upvote your own answer but you can accept it.

The reason for answering your own question would be that you think it would be interesting/useful to the Physics SE community. If you think this would be the case then yes you should go ahead and write the answer.

The only reservation I have is that your question is rather elementary. You calculate the forces by taking moments about the points where the feet touch the ground, and (in the UK) this is something you get taught in basic mechanics from around age 16. I don't know what the demographics of the Physics SE community look like, but I'd be surprised if many members didn't already know this.

But if you think it would be interesting and rewarding to write your own answer you should ignore old duffers like me and go ahead and do it!